Android build fails at AndroidSigning@3 task
After build step in my azure pipeline yml I have the below task to sign the apk files

The task AndroidSigning@3 demands JDK. Now the issue is when I add this task to the pipeline I'm seeing the below error while triggering the pipeline
**No agent found in pool test-agents-2022 which satisfies the following demand: JDK. All demands: msbuild, visualstudio, java, JDK, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.206.1
**
Pipeline runs successfully when I comment out this task.
I have checked my agent capabilities and see jdk 21 is already installed.

I tried adding the demands to the pool but no luck
**  pool:
name: test-agents-2022
demands:
- JDK**

Normally Android related tasks don't use Java 21 but 17.  But I am surprised that you need a JDK, that was only required years ago for jarsigner before apksigner took over, and it only requires a JRE not a JDK. BTW why does you config say apksigner: false?  I assume this disabled signing? Didn't you say you want sign your apk?

In the Requirements of the task AndroidSigning@3, it mentions that

Self-hosted agents must have capabilities that match the following demands to run jobs that use this task: JDK

So, you must have a capability named JDK. You can add a User-defined capability to the agent. Then the error will disappear.

